# plpy.execute('...') statements not in logs

Tags: postgresql, python, functions, plpython

How can I get the SQL statements executed by `plyp` into the postgres log files?

```
CREATE FUNCTION history_monitor() RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpythonu
    AS $_$
    ...
    plpy.execute('...')
$_$;
```

I have a function like above which gets executed if data gets inserted into a table.

I can see all statements executed via psycopg2.

How can I see the statements of the python code running in postgres executed by plpy?

Postgres Version: 9.3

Comment: You might try [auto_explain](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/auto-explain.html) and `log_nested_statements` with `log_min_duration` set to 0 to log all statements.

Comment: You should provide postgresql version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In situations like this, the [auto explain](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html) module, with `log_nested_statements` and `log_min_duration` set to 0 should show the statements executed inside of functions in PostgreSQL.